# Facebook auto login using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

I want to make page to auto login using javascript.
For example, If someone connect this page, he could connect to facebook with id and password already saved in page.

First time, I was going to use FB.login, but it looks like that it doesn't support my way.
And I found some way like connecting facebook site , filling email and password automatically and submitting it.
But I don't want that way.
I want to use just my page.

So, is there any solution about it?

Comment: Short answer, no. Long answer - you shouldn't be asking for, or storing their facebook passwords in the first place. If they are already signed into facebook, then using FB.login will work. If they aren't, there's nothing you can do without being evil.

Comment: I know saving password is wrong method in normal page, but I'm making this page for smart TV application which is made by hatml/javascript. So, I want that this page works like android facebook application(facebook application saves password and login automatically when it is on). Is there any solution about this?

Comment: It's still evil. At most, you'll want to store an access token for the user that you can continue using for a while. I was going to suggest looking into `offline_access`, but it looks like they're removing that soon. https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/